# Turning off new shop in heroes of newerth

Tags: heroes-of-newerth

When I use setsave cg_usenewshop2 false, the old shop comes back, but the new shop is still there as well.  The result is an abomination where the old shop overlays the new shop.  It's pretty annoying.  How can I turn off the new shop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the line "cg_usenewshop2" in the appropriate .cfg file, it should be located in My Documents/Heroes of Newerth.

setsave should do exactly this, but it's possible that you have your .cfg file in read-only mode which would prevent it from being edited. You might have to change this (right click-->properties-->uncheck Read-Only) to edit the file, too.

Comment: If you use `setsave cg_usenewshop2`, you won't have to make the configuration not read-only